# Saving Nested Data Before Parent is Assigned an ID

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Resume model and an Education model. Education belongs_to resume and resume has_many educations.
I'm currently using a form in Resume's `show.html.erb` view to enter data for educations just to make sure it works.

In my `routes.rb` file I have:

```
resources :resumes do
    resources :educations
end
```

In my `educations_controller.rb` file I have this:

```
def create
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:resume_id])
    @education = @resume.educations.build(education_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @education.save
        format.html { redirect_to @resume, notice: 'Education was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @education }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @education.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This allows me, in my `views/resumes/show.html.erb`to have the following:

```
<%= form_for [@resume,Education.new] do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sectionTitle %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sectionTitle %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :completed %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :completed %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :degree %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :degree %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :school %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :school %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :summary %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :summary %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is currently working and allows me to enter multiple educations per Resume.

**The issue is,** I first have to create the resume entry before creating an education entry because the education entry depends on the resume_id integer.

How can I re structure my code so that I can create multiple education entries for a specific resume that doesn't yet have an ID so that essentially, on submit the resume is assigned an ID then any subsequent educations are attached to the given resume_id and given their own education ID?

I suspect I'll probably have to use javascript which is fine, but even so, I'm not sure what to do once intercept the default form action.

Comment: You want to create resume and educations in Resume#create method with nested form right ?

Comment: Yeah, although a nested form isn't what i currently have implemented, I could make it work. However, then I'd be unsure on how to create more than one education per Resume. Thoughts? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: how u wanna design, one or many educations under each resume ?

Comment: Yes. Many educations under one resume. @7urkm3n

Comment: if i understand it right, When filling a form resume data and right below education data and create both in one submit, and make education child of resume ?

Comment: Right, so currently i have to create the resume. Then go to the show view for the specific resume like /resumes/12. There, i have the form shown in my question above, for education. The educations entered on /resumes/12 become children of that specific resume. I want to make it less arduous so that when i go to create a resume entry, I can can create multiple education entries for the specific resume at the same time. @7urkm3n

Answer (score 0):

This is just little example but it works totally fine.

In routes.rb

```
post 'add_resume_education' => 'resumes#twince'
```

In resumes_controller.rb, in your case. Use your own `MODEL` like resume and education and change passing params too.

```
def twince
     resume = Resume.create!(title: params[:data][:category_title])
     post = resume.educations.create!(sectionTitle: params[:data][:educations][:sectionTitle])
     redirect_to :back, notice: 'Yeah Created'
end
```

in HTML page:

```
<%= form_for :data, url: add_resume_education_path do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_title %>
    <%= f.text_field :category_title %>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :educations do |edu| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= edu.label :sectionTitle %><br>
       <%= edu.text_field :sectionTitle %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <br>
    <%= f.submit 'create' %>
<% end %>
```

---

Also here quite good source, [Nested Form](http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/)

Comment: Thanks for this. have been working with it for the last couple hours and it seems the educations are getting created but not being associated with the resume. Going to keep trying things. I'll post back once I figure out a  solution.

Comment: Just do what i did, It will work perfectly everything. Its sipmle.

Comment: @tfer77 do u have any validations on it ?

Comment: I currently do not, no. I think my issue is this line:
education = resume.educations.create!(params[:resume][:education])
which in the example would be: 
post = category.posts.create!(title: params[:category][:posts][:post_title], body: params[:category][:posts][:post_body])

I'm not exactly sure how to write this specific line to fit my example. Any guidance? I think title: and body: from the example are throwing me off.

Comment: @tfer77 Does Resume creates ?

Comment: as in does it get created? yes. As does the education. Maybe this will help.
https://cloudup.com/cOaBc4FZMjF I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this with me.

Comment: no better give me `server log` after submitting the form. that would be really useful.

Comment: paste it here when u get it. ill look at that.